# How can I make a Makefile determine the system's lib directory?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

While trying to install a program from source I found that it installed libraries to /usr/lib/[program]/ and because this is on a 64-bit system it didn't work. I had to copy the libraries to /usr/lib64/[program]. Note that the library files are python and therefore architecture-independent.

The Makefile has:
`libdir          = /usr/lib`

How can I make `libdir` equal `lib64` on 64-bit systems and `lib` on 32-bit?

Comment: Could you try `uname -m` on the platforms you're interested in, and tell us the results? If they're aren't too many, this could make for a simple solution.

Comment: The systems in question are `x86_64` or `i686`. I guess a better question is how can I test for this in a Makefile?

Comment: BTW: don't install from source into `/usr/bin` or `/usr/lib`, use `/usr/local` so as not to screw up your package management.

Comment: @reinierpost Yeah, I'm fixing the Makefile so that it will work properly when packaged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
MACHINE := $(shell uname -m)

ifeq ($(MACHINE), x86_64)
libdir = /usr/lib64
endif
ifeq ($(MACHINE), i686)
libdir = /usr/lib
endif
```

Comment: Thanka! I ended up using `uname -i` and checking for `i386` or `x86_64` to cover my bases more but this worked great.

Comment: @DaveForgac I have had trouble with `uname -i` printing `unknown`

Comment: That breaks on OS X :) You probably need to do a `uname -s` and look for `Darwin`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a fine solution, but if you get into situations where you have more variables to set you might consider using constructed variable names instead.  I find them easier to read but YMMV.

```
libdir.x86_64 = /usr/lib64
libdir.i686   = /usr/lib

MACHINE := $(shell uname -m)

libdir = $(libdir.$(MACHINE))
```

Comment: That breaks on OS X :) You probably need to do a `uname -s` and look for `Darwin`, and then guard the `libdir` assignment.